# how to pass array string in JavaScript function from PHP end as a argument?

Tags: php, javascript, charts, arguments

I am getting the error **missing ) after argument** list in my Firebug console.

> [emissing ) after argument http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/393131_320846714645076_100001592501599_911297_470580896_n.jpg](http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/393131_320846714645076_100001592501599_911297_470580896_n.jpg)

My question is how to pass $char_data variable in JavaScript function as a argument

Define php variable:

```
<?php 
$chart_data = "['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]"; 
$div = "graph";
?
```

Call JavaScript function with define argument

```
<script>
dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>','<?php echo $chartdata;?>')
</script>
```

A function of JavaScript

```
<script>
function dynamicChartArray(div,chartdata){
var myData = new Array(chartdata);
var myChart = new JSChart(div, 'pie');
alert(chartdata+div);
}
<script>
```

Comment: See my updates with screeshot

Comment: i was tried all of thing but the error missing ) after argument list in my Firebug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating an array out of a string in javascript, why not just just get the PHP to output it as an array to start with?

Just add an extra set of [] which javascript reads as an array.

```
$chart_data = "[['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]]";
```

then ditch the quotes on the output (which are responsible for causing the error messages)

```
 dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>', <?php echo $chartdata;?>);
```

and then myData can just equal chart data (since its already an array)

```
var myData = chartdata;
```

Comment: The code works fine in my console? Would you be able to add the javascript code that is being output by PHP (and is causing the error) to your posts at all? It may simply be that one of your values has a problem, for example if one of the values in quotes was "O'Neil" it would need escaping in order to stop it breaking the javascript.

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$chart_data = "['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]";
```

Use

```
$chart_data = "[\"NBA\",1],[\"NFL\",2],[\"MLB\",3],[\"NHL\",4]";
```

Change your call to this:

```
dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>',[<?php echo $chartdata;?>])
```

And function to this:

```
function dynamicChartArray(div,chartdata){
var myData = chartdata;
var myChart = new JSChart(div, 'pie');
alert(chartdata+div);
}
```

Comment: how to change my char_data to like this actually this chart_data contain dynamic value

Comment: create string from your dynamic values

Answer (score 2):

```
'<?php echo $chartdata;?>'
```

This is going to echo `'['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]'`.  Note how there are single quotes inside the single quotes.

```
 new Array(chartdata)
```

This will just make an array, with one element, the string `"['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]"`.

Try doing `dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>',[<?php echo $chartdata;?>])`

This will make `chartdata` an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>','<?php echo $chartdata;?>')
```

to this:

```
dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>', [<?php echo $chart_data;?>]);
```

and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `var myData = new Array(chartdata);`.

#### `chartdata` is already an array.

Comment: @Samad, simply pass `chartdata` where it needs to be sent.

Comment: @Samad, simple pass `chartdata` where it needs to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$chart_data = json_encode(array(array('NBA',1),array('NFL',2)));
```

which will produce a json string ready to echo into your script

```
string(21) "[["NBA",1],["NFL",2]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the output. I bet it is:

```
dynamicChartArray('graph','['NBA',1],['NFL',2],['MLB',3],['NHL',4]')
```

and you can already see that you have problems with the quotes.

Instead of creating a string, I suggest to create an array and use `json_encode`:

```
$chart_data = array(
    array('NBA',1),
    array('NFL',2),
    array('MLB',3),
    array('NHL',4)
);
```

and

```
dynamicChartArray('<?php echo $div;?>', <?php echo json_encode($chartdata); ?>)
```

JSON happens to be valid JavaScript as well and it gives you more possibilities to process the data on the server side.