# How to pass php array of arrays to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of arrays in PHP in this layout for example,

> "Key1" => { "id" => 1, "name" => "MyName", "address" => "USA" }
>   "Key2" => { "id" => 2, "name" => "MyName2", "address" => "Australia" }

The data in the PHP array was taken from SQL Database. Now I want to be able to use this in JavaScript.

I searched the web and people are suggesting to use JSON using this code:

```
var js_var = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>");
```

I get this error in firefox when using firebug

```
missing ) after argument list [Break On This Error]
var js_var = JSON.parse("{"Key1":{"id":"1","name":"MyName","address":"USA"...
```

Error is in right after *JSON.parse("{"Key1*

In google chrome, firebug does not report any errors

Comment: use `JSON.parse('<?php= json_encode($var); ?>');` (note the _single_ quotes.)

Comment: What's the exact value? You've trimmed potentially vital information...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass array string in javascript function from php end as a argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776376/how-to-pass-array-string-in-javascript-function-from-php-end-as-a-argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var js_var = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>');
```

Or, even better:

```
var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
```

... Since JSON is, by definition, valid JavaScript syntax for object declaration.

Comment: worked perfectly. so the double quotation marks is messing it up. didn't notice it. thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

Why go through this bizarre `json_encode` into a string to only `JSON.parse` on the client side? Useless use of encoding, really.

Try `var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;`

Comment: OK, but that's not so good if the variable is dynamically generated (e.g. based on the current page state).

Comment: @Alex: What do you mean by that? We're talking about building the initial response from the server to the client. If the client-side needs to dynamically alter the ``js_var`` variable, it's free to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is being cause by the fact you are using double-quotation marks (") to wrap the JSON string. Due to the fact that the JSON string also contains double-quotations the parser is unable to determine when the string starts and ends correctly.

Change the line to this:

```
var js_var = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>');
```

That been said JSON or JavaScript Object Notation is already a subset of the JavaScript programming language and therefore can already be parsed by the JavaScript engine so does not necessarily need to be parsed by JSON.parse.

```
var js_var = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
```

I would however only recommend this option if you are sure about the JSON you are outputting as an incorrect parsing by JSON.parse can be handled where as incorrect JSON injected directly will cause a parser error I believe.

Comment: The contents of $var is taken from database into a PHP array. Will that be an issue about the correctness of the data to be converted to JSON format?

Comment: @John In this case since you are encoding the data yourself I imagine anything that would cause a parse error in JavaScript would cause an encode error in your PHP so just make sure you handle any possible errors in the PHP.